# How to bind a dependency property to a control in WPF?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have created a `Day` class:

```
public class Day
{
    public int DayOfMonth
    {
        get { return dayOfMonth; }
    }
    public List<Entry> CalendarDayItems
    {
        get { return calendarDayItems; }
        set { calendarDayItems = value; }
    }

    private DateTime date;
    private int dayOfMonth;
    private List<Entry> calendarDayItems;

    public Day(DateTime date, List<Entry> entries)
    {
        this.date = date;
        this.dayOfMonth = date.Day;
        this.calendarDayItems = entries;
    }
}
```

Next I have created a WPF `UserControl` for which I want to bind the collection of days to the `ItemsControl`. I have created a dependency property `ObservableCollection<Day> Days` which is bound to the `ItemsControl`. Here's XAML:

```
<UserControl ... Name="CalendarMonthViewControl">
...
<ItemsControl 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=CalendarMonthViewControl, Path=Days}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <UniformGrid Rows="6" Columns="7" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="Day">
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition />
          <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- The following two bindings don't work -->
        <TextBlock 
            Grid.Column="0" 
            Text="{Binding Path=DayOfMonth}" />
        <ItemsControl 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CalendarDayItems}">
        </ItemsControl>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
...
```

I have a couple of questions:

1. Am I using the proper way to bind a dependecy property to the `ItemsControl`, i.e. is it recommended to name the control and then to reference it as a binding source?
2. The main problem is that the `TextBlock` and the second `ItemsControl` won't bind to `DayOfMonth` and `CalendarDayItems` properties of the `Day` class, respectively.

Comment: @Boris When you say "won't bind", do you mean you don't see the initial values of these properties (and the output window of VS shows binding errors) or that changes to these properties aren't shown?

Comment: @grantnz I meant when I run the application, the `TextBlock` and the `ItemsControl` are not showing any data, `DayOfMonth` value and the list of `CalendarDayItems` are not showing. They are just blank, but there are no errors or exceptions.

Comment: It is as if the binding is trying to find those properties on the control and not for the `Day` items in the collection...

Comment: If you run your app in the debugger, are there any binding errors in the Output window?

Comment: @Boris Try making your ObservableCollection<Day> Days a standard public property on your UserControl to eliminate any Dependency property related issues.  You could also post the relevant UserControl source.

Comment: @Boris, code you've shown so far is correct. The issue is either in your `CalendarMonthViewControl` code behind or in the place where you're setting this control and it's `Days` properties.

Comment: @Andy, the output window showed the errors in the debugger. This lead me to finding the answer and making the binding work. Please, post your comment as an answer, so I can mark it correct.

Comment: All, thanks for looking into this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your app in the debugger, any errors with bindings will be shown in the Output window. This can be used to figure out why a binding isn't working.

Comment: In the output window, I found that the `DayOfMonth` and `MonthEntries` were non-existing properties. Once I've checked the `Day` class I noticed that I've set `internal` accessors to these properties. Changing them to `public` resolved the binding issue. Thanks Andy for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good suggestions for resolving Q2, but for Q1 I would suggest that you set the DataContext for the UserControl and then in the ItemsControl you can just use `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Days}"`.

This allows you to easily replace the DataContext with another, for example to do simple testing of your control. It also means that if `Days` or other properties are used for other controls in your UserControl, you don't need to repeat the ElementName tags.

This mechanism is commonly used with the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) design pattern (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)), where the ViewModel is the DataContext for the View.

In your example, you could simply set the DataContext either directly in the XAML, using something like:

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding Path=CalendarMonthViewControl}}" ... />
```

Or you could set in it the code behind file.

Comment: Disagree, there is no need to put a MVVM pattern in every hole. Simple controls should be implemented in regular way, MVVM will not make it easier, probably will make it worse. OP's usage of Dependency property is correct. Also your answer seems to unclear to me, you're not answering second question and for first question you have only couple of words about **what** should be changed. You do not say how and who should set the `DataContext`.

Comment: @Snowbear, would you agree that I am binding dependency property `Days` to the `ItemsControl` in a recommendable manner? This binding works, but I wish to improve my skills, so maybe the usage of `DataContext` is a better solution?

Comment: @Boris, IMO, your way to bind it is correct, there are other slightly different options but they won't give you much benefits. If I would write such a control I would use the approach you've chosen, I do not see anything better. P.S. Sorry for spamming in answers.

Comment: @Snowbear, I'm not suggesting that this control necessarily needs to use MVVM, but it is an example of setting the DataContext. I'll update my answer to clarify.